# If I provide CLANG_DATABASE_PATH in Doxyfile do I still have to provide INPUT and INCLUDE_PATH?

Tags: clang, doxygen

I am using Doxygen for documentation of my project. I have a `compile_commands.json` file describing the source code of my project inside the directory `C:\dev\project_dir`. I set the following variables:

```
CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = YES
CLANG_DATABASE_PATH    = C:\dev\project_dir
```

So how does this work? Do I also have to set the variables `INPUT` and `INCLUDE_PATH`? It seems that all the files and the instructions to compile them, including where to get header files from, are written in the compilation database.

---

And if I do have to set the variables `INPUT` and `INCLUDE_PATH` also, what should I set them to? The compilation database lists the source and header files of the project, which are scattered among multiple different directories. How should I proceed in this situation.

Comment: You have to configure a project with clang assisted parsing just as you do with a project without the clang assisted parsing.

Comment: @albert You didn't answer my question.

Comment: I said that "You have to configure a project with clang assisted parsing just as you do with a project without the clang assisted parsing." this implies in my opinion  a.o. that you have to set the `INPUT` and `INCLUDE_PATH` etc.

Comment: @albert Did you actually try it or do you just have an assumption?

Comment: I didn't try but I have some experience with doxygen ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

So I set the following variables in the Doxyfile.

```
CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = YES
CLANG_DATABASE_PATH    = C:\dev\project_dir
```

And I set the following variables as blank:

```
INPUT =
INCLUDE_PATH =
```

`INPUT` specifies the paths to source code `*.c *.cpp` files and/or directories to be processed. `INCLUDE_PATH` specifies the paths to header code `*.h *.hpp` files and/or directories to be processed.

The `CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = YES` enables using clang compiler as the parser instead of the default doxygen parser. So if `INPUT` and `INCLUDE_PATH` are not set, then it gets the source code files and header code files from the compilation database itself. The `CLANG_DATABASE_PATH` specifies the directory in which the compilation database is stored. It grabs the file named `compile_commands.json` by default from that directory, implying that the name of the compilation database is fixed. If you name your compilation database JSON file anything else other than `compile_commands.json` doxygen won't be able to find it.

So if a clang compilation database JSON file is used all the `*.c *.cpp` files that are being compiled are placed in the `INPUT`. And all the header code files are placed in the `INCLUDE_PATH`. The clang used by doxygen parses the JSON, and every time it encounters a `-I` compiler flag it recognizes that file as a header file, adding it to the `INCLUDE_PATH`. This means that setting `INPUT` and `INCLUDE_PATH` are **not mandatory**. So if the compilation database is properly formatted, and all the header files are *explicitly* marked with the `-I`, only setting the `CLANG_DATABASE_PATH` is sufficient.

But there is a certain situation when the `INCLUDE_PATH` also needs to be set explicitly. For example if you have a source code file, which includes a header file, which includes another header file inside of it.

first.h

```c
int one(int);
```

second.h

```c
#include "first.h"
int two(int);
```

code.cpp

```cpp
#include "second.h"

int main(void) {}
```

And the command in the compilation database is such:

```
clang -I path/to/second.h -c code.cpp
```

So in this case doxygen would read that file, and it would internally set the following variables as such:

```
INPUT = code.cpp
INCLUDE_PATH = path/to/second.h
```

This means that although doxygen will index `second.h`, it will miss `first.h` since that header file isn't explicitly provided in the `-I` compilation database. That would be an error. So we need to list it explicitly in the doxyfile, an an additional include path.

```
INPUT =
INCLUDE_PATH = path\to\first.h

CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = YES
CLANG_DATABASE_PATH    = C:\dev\project_dir
```

Comment: From the documentation in respect to the `INPUT` setting: "If this tag is empty the current directory is searched." For The `INCLUDE_INPUT`: The `INCLUDE_PATH` tag can be used to specify one or more directories that contain include
files that are not input files but should be processed by the preprocessor. And for `CLANG_OPTIONS: "Note that the include paths will already be set by
doxygen for the files and directories specified with INPUT and INCLUDE_PATH.". In my opinion your conclusion about the setting of these and clang is the wrong way around.